# How to use gitlab comments to tell jenkins to do special tasks

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

Today we are sending build-trigger as notes (eg comments) från gitlab merge-requests to tell jenkins start a pipeline. Since we only had one such task we have been happy enough with just checking if a trigger sent as a note reached our pipeline and then acted on that information.

But, now we would like to add more user-requested tasks and need to inspect the comment for the type of request the user ask for.

From the documentation at https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin there are no variables that carries the information from note-trigger to the pipeline. The note seems to be discarded after the comment-regex-filter in the job-configuration in the gui.

I hope I have missed something. Otherwise we have to fetch all notes for the merge-request from gitlab to the pipeline through a rest-call.

Comment: If you're already using GitLab, why not just use GitLab CI? Otherwise, look into webhooks: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html

Comment: @nbokmans That is a question way above my paygrade :-)

Comment: I am quite sure that is not possible or easily available. I had a slightly similar issue and raised a ticket with GitLab and was got a suggestion that we can have one `jenkins job` which will read the `commit comment` and orchestrate it to call any other downstream job to perform the intended action. This requires you to build logic on Jenkins pipelines since `gitlab` can make exactly "one" call only to Jenkins. Your jenkins will then interpret it and take next course of action. Ref: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/236214

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are doing this (only difference is we are using Bitbucket). Here is the summary:

1. In Jenkins we have written code using ([jenkins shared library](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/)).
2. From within the application pipeline (jenkinsfile) we will make a call to the jenkins shared library method (say commentChecker()) to check the the git commit messages and understand what needs to happen.
3. In the shared library code commentChecker() - we will first call the Bitbucket API for the branch and get all the commit messages. In your case I think you should able to call (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html) api and get the details and parse through the messages.
4. Shared library is like a common function and all your projects can all this one function to check the commits, easy to handle and make changes.

Comment: I think the question was about _comments_ posted in the MR, and not about _commits_ message for code changes.